# How to prevent ssh-agent from starting in CentOS?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-agent

How do I stop ssh-agent from starting when logging into CentOS via openssh?

There are no references to ssh-agent in my bash startup scripts (.bashrc) or /etc/bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably started for your gnome session. To get the parent id of your ssh-agent:

```
cat /proc/$SSH_AGENT_PID/status | fgrep PPid
```

Then use the number there to look at what process that is:

```
more /proc/<PPidNUMBER_FOUND>/status.
```

On Ubuntu 12.04 you find in the first line `Name: gnome-session`

You will probably find something under `/etc/X11`:

```
grep ssh-agent /etc/X11/*
```

results in:

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.options:use-ssh-agent
```

try commenting that out en restarting X